# Extracting and Manipulating a string in C?

Tags: c

Given the following string

```
AL0100124Abbeville city                                                       2987     1353
```

I want to abstract the certain words from the string such as 
"AL" "Abbeville" and 1353

I understand how to get the first two words and have following

```
char str[2];
strncpy(str, original, 2);
str[2] = '\0';
```

But how do i get the word "Abbeville" and deal with the white space?

**EDIT:** 
I want to store each of these each words in a different char variable,
So for instance

```
char str = "AL",
char str2 = "Abbevile"
char str3 = "1353"
```

I read the original list of strings from a file, the above is just an example of one line

Here is how I my code looks

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("places.txt", "r");
char fileLine[200];
while(fgets(fileLine, 200,fp )!= NULL){
        char state[3];
        char city[20];
        //char latitude[10];
        //char longitude[10];

        strncpy(state,fileLine, 2);
        state[2] = '\0';

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what are the criterion for being a 'word'.

Comment: @RashikHasnat i want the word to be a string(char)

Comment: `char str[2];` --> `char str[3];`

Comment: `str[2] = '\0';` writes to `str`'s 3rd element, which is out of the bound of the two-element array `str`.

Comment: Also, how do you define your string?

Comment: So how does '1353' become a 'string' according to your definition?

Comment: @Marievi i reading that string from a file

Comment: `char city[15] = ""; strncpy(city, original + 9), 14);`

Comment: What is the rule that separates the words? Is it that each alpha numerical sequence follows a numerical sequence and that alphanumerical sequences may contain white space? Or are the words at fixed positions?

Comment: Yes but could you show the code where you read it?

Comment: @Marievi i have added more to the question

Comment: @alk regarding your comment about abstracting the city value, it is possible that I might need more than 14 characters or less than that. It can't be a constant value, where a city name can be "Blue Springs"

Comment: You either need to know the maximum possible length a city in your input may have, or need to know a well defined delimiter for the city's name. If you know neither the problem is unsolvable in a 100% manner.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, accessing `str[2]` will result in undefined behavior:

```
char str[2]; // Declaration of a char array with the length '2'
             // Since we are 0-Based it has two elements: 0 and 1
str[2] = '\0'; // Here you will access the third element, which is not defined
```

If you want to copy `X` elements, you need a array with the length `X+1` (`char str[3]` in this case).

Example usage:

```
#include <string.h>

char str1[20] = "Here you go with your input information";
char str2[5];
strncpy(str2, str1, 4);
str2[4] = '\0';
printf("First string: %s\n", str2); // prints "Here"
strncpy(str2, &str1[12], 4);
str2[4] = '\0';
printf("Second string: %s\n", str2); // prints "with"
```

Comment: @RRP Changed memcpy to strncpy